# How to auto align grid items?? [Shopify]

Tags: javascript, html, css, shopify

It's possible to align all the grid items if they have different content size???
Check the my image below as  example: [image]

Test Site : https://strokes-test.myshopify.com/

Code for li.griditems

```
  <li class="grid__item grid__item--{{section.id}} {{ grid_item_width }}">
        {% include 'product-grid-item', max_height: max_height, product: product, show_vendor: section.settings.show_vendor %}
      </li>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this css.

```
.grid--view-items {
    overflow: auto;
    margin-bottom: -35px;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.grid--view-items li.grid__item .products {
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.products .product_left {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    align-items: flex-end;
}
```

It will look like this.
[image]